# I have a button disable in my flutter app but i want the button to be active once the user starts typing the otp message

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app which take an OTP.My issue is i have my button disable by default and want it enable when the user start inputing the otp code.

i added a value listiner to the firts otp field to be enable the button when the user starts typing the otp,but the button is **disable** when you finish inputing the code.i want the button to be **enable** when the otp field are filled.

`

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'KindaCode',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // 4 text editing controllers that associate with the 4 input fields
  final TextEditingController _fieldOne = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _fieldTwo = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _fieldThree = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _fieldFour = TextEditingController();

  // This is the entered code
  // It will be displayed in a Text widget
  String? _otp;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('KindaCode'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text('Phone Number Verification'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          // Implement 4 input fields
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              OtpInput(_fieldOne, true), // auto focus
              OtpInput(_fieldTwo, false),
              OtpInput(_fieldThree, false),
              OtpInput(_fieldFour, false)
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _otp = _fieldOne.text +
                      _fieldTwo.text +
                      _fieldThree.text +
                      _fieldFour.text;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Submit')),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          // Display the entered OTP code
          Text(
            _otp ?? 'Please enter OTP',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create an input widget that takes only one digit
class OtpInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool autoFocus;
  const OtpInput(this.controller, this.autoFocus, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      width: 50,
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: autoFocus,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        controller: controller,
        maxLength: 1,
        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            counterText: '',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)),
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (value.length == 1) {
            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: please update your code and show us the full code including the button you want to enable/disable

Answer (score 0):

in `TextField` there is argument

```
onChanged: (value) {
                  // your code
                }
```

You can change your state here

Comment: edit the code you can have a look,i want the button to be disable when the optfields are empty and enable when the optfields are field.

Answer (score 0):

**write this to onchange of every textfield**

```
    if((_fieldOne.text+_fieldTwo.text+_fieldThree.text+_fieldFour.text).isEmpty)
    {
       disable the button
    }else{
       enable the button
    }
```

Comment: i tried this but nothing happed

Comment: can you update the code with a simple reproducible example? and the scenario you want exactly.

Comment: okay,i want the button to be diable when the otp fields are empty.

Comment: bool isButtonDisable = true; default disable the button

Comment: edit the code you can have a look,i want the button to be disable when the optfields are empty and enable when the optfields are field.